# Unable to connect to external server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to an external server to access a database. I have checked all the information in terms of id and password details and they are correct. Have also checked on the server side and it is live and I've created a table for testing.

I am a bit halted with the idea of where am I supposed to run the codes to connect to the database. All examples covers the syntac and all but not really mentioning where I should run the php script. I am current storing it in my localhost where I installed xampp which I believe is not the right way. Have also just tried running the php file by placing it on the desktop and opening it. That doesn't work either.

Please advice how to do it. I believe it is a simple process but somehow it is not working for me. Thanks.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql2.000webhost.com", "username", "password", "databasename"); 

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

> Error Message: Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on
>   line 9 Failed to connect to MySQL: A connection attempt failed because
>   the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond

Comment: Thank you for giving us your password

Comment: Delete your question; **now**.

Comment: Cute considering you thought that was my password. It isnt.

Comment: It could very well have been actual DB credentials. Some actually do.

Comment: So your free host doesn't have a responsive server? Surprised?

Comment: If you feel you should be able to connect, default TCP debugging is in order. I don't know what those would be in Windows, but I assume there are equivalents to linux' `netcat` & `tcpdump` there.

Comment: I am not surprised if that is the reason. Trying to be sure that that is the reason rather something else I am doing wrong.

Comment: You're certain that `mysql2.000webhost.com` is the actual host? They have many.

Comment: When I registered a set of log in details to the database, these 4 informations were automatically given to be used as follows: $mysql_host = "mysql2.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "database_name";
$mysql_user = "user";
$mysql_password = "password";

Comment: Check to see if you are able to get through the firewall, MySQL is usually blocked as the default.

Comment: Not working even with firewall off. Doesn't connect even when I try via SQL workbench port 3306.

Answer (score 0):

1) a $conn is executed before a query is done - so if your script php script needs to access the db anything you do before doing an actual sql execution you would need to do the $conn

2) if you are running xampp (or any variants) load up the startup page and it usually tell you which PORT, LOCALHOST, username and password (typically root and blank) - check if that works first.

3) regarding remote servers - most of the time for security purpose, you cannot simply remote in from the outside and you maybe firewall. Sometimes you can as it is easier to use a mysql workbench than phpmyadmin but thats up to the hosting.

Verify all those first, and you should be able to connect when you run test.php.

Comment: I am new to this so please forgive the possible silly question. Do I need xampp to connect to an external server? Although I have it, I thought it was not a necessity and only used as a localhost for testing purposes.

Comment: xampp is for local environment. After you build your code you upload your code to your given server with its own DB's setting.